# SQLSTATE: Integrity constraint violation: values (, pi insertion, 6))?

Tags: laravel, api

i have included i verifycsrvtokens the path.When i give the date in postman it is taking null.

it is in my controller 
public function addTask(Request $request)
    {
        //to insert the details

```
    $library = new timeSheetsModel;

    $library->ondate = $request->ondate;
    echo $library->ondate;
    $library->text=$request->text;
    $library->hours = $request->hours;
    $library->save();
    $library->json_encode($library);
```

code in api.php

Route::post('/Insert','TimesheetsController@addTask');

Comment: can you show the Timesheetmodel? How many columns are there?

Comment: i got the solution @saroj shrestha i have used get in postman instead of post method.anyways thanks for response:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used post method in postman.so it happend make sure that which method you are using in your code is correct.